# what if there are two kinds of users

Tags: database, database-design

so far I have these three tables userRole, user and role...I get lot of if questions in my head...now my question is what if there are two kinds of users like normal user or premium user where they get different kind of service...do you put an attribute `roleId` inside the user table or do you make a totally separate table ?

```
User table

UserID - int
Username - varchar(25)
Password - varchar(25)
Firstname - varchar(50) etc...
```

.

```
Roles table

RoleId - int
Role Description - varchar(25)
```

.

```
User_Roles table

UserId - int (with a foregin key to the Users table)
RoleId int (foreign key to the Roles table)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of the `User_Roles` table is that it allows users to have multiple roles. If users can only ever have one role, then you can put the `roleId` directly on the `User` table.

Can you think of a use case for users having multiple roles? [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), for example, only allows one role per user. Different roles have different [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), so you can have a complex privilege system with one role per user.

Comment: that makes sense, I will put roleId directly on the User table , so the user can have multiple or one role

Comment: @Dana if you put the roleId on the User table, users can only have one role.

Comment: sorry I didnt see your edited answer...that makes sense why I see sometimes role_id inside users table!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to achieve.

If all type of users have the same informations then you have User and UserRole.

If depending on the type of user, they have different informations, then User will have the information that both type can have. You'll then have tables like PremiumUser to add additional info to a PremiumUser, making UserRole table useless in this case since if you are looking for premium members, you have them in the PremiumUser table.

If a user can have multiple roles, then it can be done in multiple ways depending on what you need. Using a UserRole, User and a User_UserRole tables to allow multiple roles for a user.

All in all, it always depends on what you need to do.

Edit: To explain a little more clearly, here are some examples with the tables in quote:

**One role per user, same information...**

> User (Contain UserRoleId) and UserRole

**Multiple roles per user, same information...**

> User, User_UserRole (Contain UserId and UserRoleId to link them together) and UserRole

**One role per user, different information...**

> User (All users use this table), StandardUser (Contain UserId) and PremiumUser (Contain UserId)

**Multiple roles per user, different information...**

> Same as above as StandardUser and PremiumUser can both have a similar UserId